# way to redirect page to www using virtual host configuration in sites-available for apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

now days I create two files one for example.com and one for www.example.com  because the wild card  *.example.com doesn't work right for accessing example.com 
my question is how do I make example.com redirect to www.example.com using apache and not something like php. So I can have one virtual host configuration per domain.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SeverName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

in your virtual host configuration...

Then you can redirect `non-www` to `www` with something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```