# Redirect example.com to www.example.com VPS & Apache2

Tags: debian, domain, vps, apache-2.2

I have a VPS and a domain name registered with the provider.

When I enter www.example.com my site is displayed correctly, but entering example.com does not work. I am able to ping www.example.com.

I added the following line to my apache2 default vhosts file:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

But this did not work.

The VPS is a Debian5 OS.

Any ideas?
Note: There is no option via a provided control panel to add this, it's a basic package I purchased

I know this post answers it but there are no extra comments and I'd like to know if it's the best way:
[way to redirect page to www using virtual host configuration in sites-available for apache2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/276832/way-to-redirect-page-to-www-using-virtual-host-configuration-in-sites-available-f)

Thanks

Comment: Please post the results of `nslookup example.com` and `nslookup www.example.com`, to verify that they're both pointing to your VPS correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get DNS resolution to work, you need to have an A record for 'example.com', not just 'www.example.com'. Once that's there, what you've done so far will probably work. This sounds like an DNS issue so far.

Comment: Yes, I added a new A record for www.example.com and this worked, Thanks.

Comment: a cname record will do nicely, it's just subtly different; depends on what you're aiming for

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question. The answer you link to is indeed a good example of doing the redirect. The first RewriteCond may not be required if you're not using SSL, but it should not do any harm.